# i want to add new column as product image at starting of the table and add image to it in my admin/sales/order/ view page, pls help to sort this out!

Tags: magento2

Product Image
             
         
         
                  
                    
                        product_img
                    
                
             
                 Vendor_Extension::order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml
             
         
     
 

i tried this but it is adding COLUMN  at the end of table

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom module.

You need to override /vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/items/renderer/defult.phtml

So in your custom module create sales_order_view.xml file at
[Vendor]/[Module]/view/adminhtml/layout/**sales_order_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>        
        <referenceBlock name="default_order_items_renderer">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">[Vendor]_[Module]::order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now create default.phtml file at [Vendor]/[Module]/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/items/renderer/**default.phtml**

```
<?php /** @var \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items\Renderer\DefaultRenderer $block */ ?>
<?php $_item = $block->getItem() ?>
<?php $block->setPriceDataObject($_item) ?>
<tr>
    <?php $i = 0;
    $columns = $block->getColumns();
    $lastItemNumber = count($columns) ?>
    <td>
    <?php $product =  $_item->getProduct();?>
    <?php $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();?>
    
    <?php  $imagewidth=100;
    $imageheight=100;
    $imageHelper  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
    $image_url = $imageHelper->init($product, 'small_image')->setImageFile($product->getSmallImage())->resize($imagewidth, $imageheight)->getUrl();
     ?>
     <img src="<?php echo $image_url;?>" />
    </td>
     <?php foreach ($columns as $columnName => $columnClass):?>
        <?php $i++; ?>
        <td class="<?= /* @noEscape */ $columnClass ?><?= /* @noEscape */ ($i === $lastItemNumber ? ' last' : '') ?>"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getColumnHtml($_item, $columnName) ?></td>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>
```

**OR YOUR CAN DOWNLOAD THIS MODULE** https://github.com/magecomp/Magento-2-Product-Images-Order-View-
I haven't tested it in the latest version of Magento. But I think It will work

Comment: thanks for your information, but table heading is not coming

Comment: You can download the module which I said at the end of my answer. It is working as you need.